# appium-Interactions are not available for this element

Tags: java

[**Using XPath locators is not recommended and can lead to fragile tests. Ask your development team to provide unique accessibility locators instead!**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCkbr.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i was having a problem to access an element in eclipse >>then i try this    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@class='android.view.View' and ./parent::*[@class='android.view.View' and ./parent::*[@class='android.view.View' and ./parent::*[@class='android.view.View']]]]/*[@class='android.widget.EditText'])[1]")).click();